# how to get transactions per hour for given ERC20 tokens on blockchain? (preferably with python)

Tags: blockchain, tokens, statistics

how to get transactions per hour for given ERC20 tokens on blockchain? (preferably with python)

Lets say i want to get number of transaction per hour for EOS token.

Comment: Consider re-asking at [EOS.io site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/116927/eosio/visit).

Comment: Do you mean average transactions per hour? Or getting the last hour of EOS token transfers?